# Dropping constraint deletes rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble dropping all the constraints in a database.  I have a table `tblBrowser`.  If I run this query:

```
SELECT ID FROM tblBrowser
```

It returns 1575337 rows.  If I then run this query:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (ID INT IDENTITY (1, 1), tblName VARCHAR(256), ConstraintName VARCHAR(256))


-- Remove the indexes
INSERT INTO #tmp (tblName, ConstraintName)
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE 
    WHERE 
    CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = 'MyDB'
    AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'IX_%'


    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT tblName, ConstraintName
    FROM #tmp
    ORDEr BY ID

OPEN cur

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @Constraint VARCHAR(256)

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Name, @Constraint

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping constraint: ' + @Constraint + ' from ' + @Name
    EXEC ('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + @Name + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @Constraint +']' )
    IF(@@ERROR <> 0)
        GOTO ERR_UPDATING
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Name, @Constraint
END

GOTO DONE

ERR_UPDATING:
    RAISERROR('Error dropping constraints', 11, 1)

DONE:

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
DROP TABLE #tmp
```

then run `SELECT ID FROM tblBrowser`

it returns 1575296 rows.  What could cause this?  I dont have any triggers setup to delete on index removal.  I am using MS SQL Server 2008

edit: Ive tried using SQL Profiler to see if anything is being executed to delete the rows.  There isnt.

Comment: Are you sure no one else do it? It doesn't make any sense. Try to prepare testing environment, set SINGLE user mode and rerun your code.

Comment: My first question is why are you dropping every constraint in your database in the first place?

Comment: @SeanLange Its an extremely old DB from a prior version of our software and is being upgraded.  I guess the previous devs thought it simpler to just drop all the constraints and rebuild them after all the changes have been applied.

Comment: Why have you come to the conclusion that dropping the constraints is responsible for rows being deleted from `tblBrowser`? Unless you have a very odd DDL trigger it won't be.

Comment: @MartinSmith Because if i run the mentioned queries in the order above, thats what happened.  I know it shouldnt, but something is removing rows on the constraint drop.  And there are no triggers...at all.

Comment: Some other connection running a  concurrent delete would be my assumption

Comment: I would say that just because it is has always been that way doesn't mean it is a good approach. Do you have some script that adds them back or something? And since the drop is dynamic how do you know that you add them all back.

Comment: I would create a work table, and insert all the IDs from the first table into it. Then run your script, and do an outer join from the work table to the result, and find out which rows are now missing. Look at those rows in the original table, and see what they are. Also, have you run a CheckDB on the database?